# Cascading GeoWebCache Servers

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

I am trying to address some latency issues accessing US based servers from Asia

We are using GeoWebCache in front of two GeoServer instances, based in the USA.

One thought that occurred to me was to deploy additional GeoWebCache Servers, but instead of having them hit a GeoServer instance, locally or remotely, have them front another GeoWebCache instance (Cascaded) located in the USA.

The thought behind this is that the tiles will already be cached on the "Master" GeoWebCache which simply serves the requested tiles to the GeoWebCache instance requesting it in Asia. This should eliminate the need to have additional Geoserver Instances to service Tile requests

Has anyone done this before or have any thoughts as to whether it will work as I expect?

Comment: Do you have control over the original Geoserver & GeoWebCache? If your data doesn't change much, you could just copy the tiles and serve it out as a TMS from the servers in Asia. That will be much faster and easier to manage.

Comment: Yep, have full control, the size of the tile copy will be an issue, it will be world wide, at least to zoom level 9, possibly more, that's why was figuring on first user to look at a detailed area triggers the tile look up, but it may be worth copying first few layers (Some layers will change monthly, by country)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have set up similar systems and it works very well - we saw speed ups of up to 25 times over the base WMS system (there was a slow satellite link involved). All you have to worry about is making sure the grid sets match up.